# Bounded in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Consider any random variable $X$ with cdf $F_X(x)$. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, we
can bound $X$ in the following way. Because the lower $limit$ of $F_X$ is $0$ and its upper
$limit$ is $1$, we can find $η_1$ and $η_2$ such that

$F_X(x) < \epsilon/2 \text{ for } x ≤ η_1 \text{ and } F_X(x) > 1 − (\epsilon/2) \text{ for } x ≥ η_2$.

Let $η = max\{|η_1|, |η_2|\}$. Then

$P[|X| ≤ η] = F_X(η) − F_X(−η − 0) ≥ 1 − (\epsilon/2) − (\epsilon/2) = 1 − \epsilon$.

(Hogg, Craig pg. 333)

When does the equality hold in:

$F_X(η) − F_X(−η − 0) ≥ 1 − (\epsilon/2) − (\epsilon/2)$?

In my opinion,

$F_X(−η) < \epsilon/2$

$F_X(η) > 1 − (\epsilon/2)$

Therefore,

$F_X(η) − F_X(−η − 0) > 1 − (\epsilon/2) − (\epsilon/2)$

Shouldn't this be just $>$ rather than $\ge$ or I'm missing something?

Comment: You are right. From $>$ it follows $\ge$ which presumably is enough for the authors.